# Unity2D: Have multiple objects rotate around the SAME center but starting from offset positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my three floating 2D platforms in my game to rotate around the SAME center. I have achieved this as so:

```
public GameObject Object;

public float RotateSpeed;
public float Radius;

private Vector2 _centre;
private float _angle;

private void Start()
{
    _centre = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{

    _angle += RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    var offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(_angle), Mathf.Cos(_angle)) * Radius;
    Object.transform.position = _centre + offset;
}
```

It works just fine, however - only for ONE plattform. If I add more platforms to the mix, they either all start from the same position in within our imaginary circle around the center OR, if I offset them, they all rotate with a different center (if the offset is x=2, then the center also is offset by 2). How do I make say 3 plattforms circle around the same center but starting on 3 different starting points ON the circle? (Like 0°, 180°, 270°) or so? (Currently, all 3 start at 0)

Thank you

EDIT:

This is how I would like ti to rotate. The 4 rectangles are the plattforms. They all are to rotate around the imaginary center. They are all the same speed so the never get closer to one another. Also, they all stay upright. The blue lines and red lines are also imaginary. There is no object in the center. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: and why not make them all children of the same GameObjet and rotate only that parent object?

Comment: Please see this [Unity's docs][1]


  [1]: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

You can also randomize the position.

Comment: That is a good idea, however, the effect is not really the same. Instead of multiple platforms rotating around the same center the are now all being rotated the same in one way. this is not how I want this...

Comment: Could you make a simple drawing about how you want then to rotate?

Comment: @Morasiu check my edit :)

Comment: And your script works for one platform?

Comment: it does. just not all of them. they all start from the same point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable: `private float _angle;` as public: `public float _angle;`.

After this, go to the inspector by clicking on the object the script is attached to and look for a variable named "angle". Change this variable to different angles for each platform.

Comment: Interesting take on things. But this leads to some odd effects pretty hard to describe. It is not really like the windmill in the picture.

Comment: MY BAD. THIS DID THE TRICK. AWESOME!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Vector2 _centre is being instantiated as the initial position of the object, try to get the transform of a pivot instead of getting the transform of the object itself

```
public float RotateSpeed;
public float Radius;

public Transform _centre; // in the inspector input the pivot transform
public float _angle; // set it in the inspector
// private float _angle; use this with the code in the start method

private void Start()
{
    /*
    _angle = Mathf.asin((pivot.position.x - transform.position.x)/Radius);
    */
}

private void Update()
{

    _angle += RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    var offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(_angle) * Radius, Mathf.Cos(_angle)) * Radius;
    transform.position = _centre + offset;
}
```

Make sure to place your platform in a coherent position around the pivot of rotation.